# Call to super needs try/catch

Tags: java, inheritance, exception

I am working on an assignment where I am told that I need to create a class (Call it ClassB) that must extend a given class (Call it ClassA). The only problem is that the code inside of the constructor of ClassA may throw an exception, so when I create my constructor for ClassB, I am trying to wrap a try/catch block around the call to super(), but of course, that doesn't work since super has to be the first call.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Add a throws clause to your subclass constructor..

Comment: @RohitJain It does work. But why? It works only for the constructor or generally for every methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public ClassB extends ClassA {
    public ClassB() throws MyClassAException {
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your exception in the throws clause of your sub class constructor: -

```
class ClassA {
    ClassA() throws Exception {

    }
}
public class Demo extends ClassA {
    Demo() throws Exception {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Demo d = new Demo();   // Handle exception here.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, of course, but don't name classes capitalized versions of keywords (even though it's legal)

Answer (score 1):

`ClassB` should have a static method

```
public static ClassB makeClassB() {
    try {
        return new ClassB();
    }
    catch(Exception exc) {
        // whatever logic you are currently performing to swallow
        // presumably you have some default ClassB to return as part of this logic?
    }
```

that will wrap the construction of `ClassB` with a try/catch.  Client code will call `makeClassB()` and the constructor to `ClassB` will be `private` and throwing.